# React exhaustive-deps rule flagging missing dependencies from custom hooks

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

*Disclaimer: I searched SO and I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58523437/exhaustive-deps-rule-doesnt-recognise-result-of-custom-hook-as-react-reference) to be reeeeaaaaaally close to mine, but I did not fully understand the [only answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68350135/15958755). I added a post to ask more explanation (I cannot add comments because I lack reputation) but it was deleted as it was not an answer, hence the new thread I am forced to create here.*

I need some explanation about the `exhaustive-deps` rule. I think I am missing something.

Thanks for your lights! :)

The React doc states that:

> React guarantees that setState function identity is stable and won’t change on re-renders. This is why it’s safe to omit from the useEffect or useCallback dependency list.

[(source)](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate)

However, consider this:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

// Writing a custom hook that only calls `useState` and returns what `useState` returns
const useMyOwnStateHook = initialValue => useState(initialValue);

const MyComponent = () => {
  // Here we have a direct call to `useState`
  const [, setStandardState] = useState('');
  // Here we call `useState` in our hook
  const [, setMyOwnState] = useMyOwnStateHook('');

  useEffect(() => {
    // This call is safe and does not raise any linting error, as per the doc (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate)
    setStandardState('');
    // This call triggers the following error in the console:
    // Line 19:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'setMyOwnState'. Either include it
    // or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    setMyOwnState('');
  }, []);
  return <span></span>
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Here I do not understand why the calls to `setStandardState` and `setMyOwnState` are not both safe.
I have such dependencies all over my code and it really burdens the dependency arrays of my `useEffect`s and I would love to understand how I could get rid of them :-)

I am using the following versions of React in my `package.json`:

```
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-scripts": "4.0.3",
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I don't think the linter knows what you know about your hook's inner functions. It does not dive deep into every function to see if it's built from safe functions. // Have you considered 'Advanced Configuration' to let it know? See https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks#advanced-configuration

Comment: Thanks for your answer ;-) However, if I understand correctly this can be used to let the linter analyse the dependencies of a custom hook. But my hook does not have any dependency array. I think it would be useful if I had created something like `useMyOwnEffect(somevar, [somevar])`.

Comment: Looks like that. Sorry! I'm stumped, but be sure to read all the options listed at https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies

Comment: I just read this carefully, but found nothing related to my case. This doc explains how some "external"/simple/non-react-hook-y function can be wire to a `useEffect`. In my case, I have some special function: a hook, which is thus using other hooks (i.e. `useState`) and returning its data.
Except if I missed something in the doc, this use case is not mentionned and thus, my problem still exists :-(

Answer (score 0):

If `setMyOwnState` doesn't change between renders (like a setState function), you could simply list it as a dependency, and not worry about it causing any unwanted side-effects, as it will never change.
This is how `react-redux` handles the same issue with their `useDispatch` hook

If `setMyOwnState` **can** change between renders, then it would make sense that react would warn you about it

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I do ;-) However, it does add a lot of things in my dependency array. That is why I was wondering if there was something to do to prevent this behavior, so that the "safeness" of `setMyOwnState` (which is created by `useState`) could be passed over to the `useEffect`.